# Disable call stack table but enable formatted var_dump in xdebug

Tags: xdebug, var-dump

how i should configure xdebug to show formatted var_dump, but disable call stack tables ?
those are my current entries in php.ini

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.collect_includes=0
xdebug.collect_params=0
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.coverage_enable=0
xdebug.extended_info=0
```

and the tables are still there

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you just set `xdebug.default_enable=0`. You will still get formatted var_dump() output then, but no stack traces.